# When to create and release NSOperationQueue?

Tags: objective-c, nsoperationqueue

I need an NSOperationQueue to use with NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest but most of the example code I've seen doesn't show it in the context of a working app. 
Should  NSOperationQueues be alloc'ed for each NSURLConnection and released in completionHandler of NSURLConnection or should it be a property alloc'ed in viewDidLoad and released in dealloc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you're managing a custom queue, the convenience methods on NSOperationQueue, `+mainQueue`, and `+currentQueue` are all you need.  They will return constant internal queues that you don't have to worry about memory management-wise.  If you do need to maintain your own operation queue, treat it as though it were a top-level object.  Namely: initialize it early (preferably in `-init`) and deallocate it late in `-dealloc`.

Comment: If those convenience methods point to the queue for the main thread, will my NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest then hold up the main thread?

Comment: Asynchronous requests will return immediately, but will block the thread.

Comment: Which kinda defeats the purpose. I guess I'm creating one in '-init'. Thanks.